# Programmatic scroll to offset expressed in pixel with respect to leading anchor, in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, uiscrollview, scrollview

I'm trying to implement [this](https://streamable.com/dp7n8n) kind of functionality in SwiftUI. The basic idea is that I have a slider and a `ScrollView`, and moving the slider around lets me scroll through the `ScrollView` content (which is not necessarily a video as shown in the above example, it can be any view).

Of course `ScrollViewReader` doesn't wrap `UIScrollView.setContentOffset` and only offers `scrollTo(_ id: Hashable [, anchor: UnitPoint])`, that doesn't let me control the offset as I would like to.

In my interpretation, the `Slider` will produce a number between 0 and 1, and then you obtain the corresponding offset to scroll to (with respect to the leading anchor) using `lerp` on the value obtained from the `Slider`'s binding, where a basic implementation for `lerp` might be the following:

```
extension Range where Bound: BinaryFloatingPoint {
    func lerp(_ t: Bound) -> Bound {
        return (1-t)*self.lowerBound + t*self.upperBound
    }
}

extension ClosedRange where Bound: BinaryFloatingPoint {
    func lerp(_ t: Bound) -> Bound {
        return (1-t)*self.lowerBound + t*self.upperBound
    }
}
```

So I made an attempt to hack around the limitation of the `ScrollViewReader` trying to avoid `Introspect` and `UIViewRepresentable`/`UIViewControllerRepresentable`, that kinda flows as follows:

1. Add an overlay to the ScrollView's content that fills the entire size with `frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)` and is `.leading` aligned.
2. The overlay will contain a simple `Rectangle()` with `.clear` background and `.contentShape(Rectangle())`, whose position with respect to the `.leading` anchor of the `ScrollView`'s content is controlled using a `@State private var offsetAnchor: CGFloat` variable, initially `.zero` and a static id assigned to it, eg `.id("scrollAnchor")`.
3. When I want to move the content of the `ScrollView` to a given offset, first thing I set `offsetAnchor` to the desired offset, and then invoke `scrollProxy.scrollTo(scrollAnchor)`.

Unfortunately the workaround didn't work and it seems to scroll to random offsets (which doesn't mean it's actually random, just I couldn't figure out the criteria). Here is a very basic implementation of my idea

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var inputValue: String = ""
    @State private var contentOffset: CGFloat = .zero {
        didSet {
            self.updateOffset("scrollAnchor")
        }
    }
    @State private var updateOffset: (String) -> Void = { _ in }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollViewReader { scrollProxy in
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: true) {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Colors.teal500)
                        .frame(width: 1000, height: 100)
                        .overlay(
                            ZStack {
                                ForEach(1..<40) { i in
                                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                        Rectangle()
                                            .fill(Colors.white)
                                            .frame(width: 1, height: 10)
                                        
                                        Text("\(i*25)")
                                            .font(.caption)
                                    }
                                    .offset(x: CGFloat(i*25))
                                }
                            }
                            .fillMaxWidth(alignment: .leading)
                        ,alignment: .topLeading)
                        .overlay(
                            ZStack {
                                Rectangle()
                                    .fill(Color.red)
                                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                                    .frame(width: 1, height: 100)
                                    .position(x: self.contentOffset, y: 50)
                                    .onAppear {
                                        self.updateOffset = { id in
                                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                                                scrollProxy.scrollTo(id)
                                            }
                                        }
                                            
                                    }
                                    .id("scrollAnchor")

                            }
                                .fillMaxWidth(alignment: .leading)
                            , alignment: .leading
                        )
                }
            }
            
            TextField(
                    "Scroll offset:",
                    text: self.$inputValue
                )
            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            
            Button(action: {
                self.contentOffset = CGFloat(Int(inputValue) ?? 0)
            }) {
                Text("Scroll to input offset")
            }

        }
        .fillMaxSize(alignment: .leading)
    }
}
```

Where `Colors.teal500` is a syntactic sugar for `#319795` color, and the `fillMaxWidth()`/`fillMaxHeight()`/`fillMaxSize()` are implemented as follows:

```
struct FillMaxSize: ViewModifier {
    private var alignment: Alignment?
    
    init(alignment: Alignment?) {
        self.alignment = alignment
    }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if self.alignment != nil {
            return content
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: self.alignment!)
        } else {
            return content
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
}

struct FillMaxWidth: ViewModifier {
    private var alignment: Alignment?
    
    init(alignment: Alignment?) {
        self.alignment = alignment
    }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if self.alignment != nil {
            return content
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: self.alignment!)
        } else {
            return content
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
    }
}

struct FillMaxHeight: ViewModifier {
    private var alignment: Alignment?
    
    init(alignment: Alignment?) {
        self.alignment = alignment
    }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if self.alignment != nil {
            return content
                .frame(minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: self.alignment!)
        } else {
            return content
                .frame(minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func fillMaxSize(alignment: Alignment? = nil) -> some View {
        return self.modifier(FillMaxSize(alignment: alignment))
    }
    
    func fillMaxWidth(alignment: Alignment? = nil) -> some View {
        return self.modifier(FillMaxWidth(alignment: alignment))
    }
    
    func fillMaxHeight(alignment: Alignment? = nil) -> some View {
        return self.modifier(FillMaxHeight(alignment: alignment))
    }
}
```

I need help either correcting what's wrong with my implementation (I suspected that `scrollTo` might be invoked before the "scrollAnchor" is moved to the new position, but this doesn't seem to be the case since I tried to execute the `scrollTo` action with few seconds delay and nothing changed), or some hint to get this working.

Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

I have generally found that `ScrollViewProxy` needs to be helped as much as possible by keeping the hierarchy flat and avoiding any possible confusion about exactly which ids are being scrolled to. I should think it also helps to stick to simple `HStack` or `VStack` layout designs, avoiding offsets or other adjustments of position.

You have explained that you want to scroll horizontally. So I would suggest using the main content of the body for the calibrated `ScrollView` based on a simple `HStack`, then overlay the interesting content using `.overlay`. The overlay automatically adopts the size of the main content:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var inputValue: String = ""
    @State private var contentOffset = 0.0

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
            VStack {
                ScrollViewReader { scrollProxy in
                    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: true) {
                        HStack(spacing: 0) {

                            // The main content consists of a row of rectangles
                            // that are 1-pixel wide, each associated with an
                            // identifier that corresponds to the index position
                            ForEach(0..<1000, id: \.self) { pixel in
                                Rectangle()
                                    .frame(width: 1)
                                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                            }
                        }
                        .overlay(

                            // The scale is shown as an overlay
                            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                                ForEach(0..<40) { i in
                                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                        Rectangle()
                                            .fill(Color.white)
                                            .frame(width: 1, height: 10)

                                        Text("\(i*25)")
                                            .font(.caption)
                                            .allowsTightening(true)
                                            .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)

                                        Spacer()
                                    }
                                    .frame(width: 25, alignment: .leading)
                                }
                            }
                            .background(Color.teal)
                        )
                    }
                    .frame(height: 100)
                    .onAppear {
                        scrollProxy.scrollTo(0, anchor: .leading)
                    }
                    .onChange(of: contentOffset) { newOffset in
                        scrollProxy.scrollTo(Int(newOffset), anchor: .leading)
                    }
                }
                // A slider for adjusting the scroll position interactively
                Slider(
                    value: $contentOffset,
                    in: 0...(1000 - geometryProxy.size.width),
                    step: 1
                )
                .padding()

                // Allow an explicit scroll position to be entered manually
                TextField(
                    "Target offset",
                    text: $inputValue
                )
                .frame(width: 100)
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)

                Button("Scroll to target offset") {
                    contentOffset = Double(inputValue) ?? 0.0
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 400)
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your effort to help. However I'm kind of concerned with the performance because the content of the `ScrollView` will end up being an image captured from a spectrogram, which can easily get to be 10k+ pixels wide and I'm kinda concerned this approach of drawing a rectangle for each pixel will cause stutters as the project scales. For instance what if I'm adding a `MagnificationGesture`? This would mean that on a 2.0x zoom level the image could 20k pixels wide.

Comment: Well ScrollViewProxy works with ids, not with pixel positions, so you need to build the view using items that have ids. But the rectangles do not necessarily need to be 1 pixel wide, they don't even need to be equal size. They just need to be as wide as the lowest level of scrolling granularity and/or your scrolling stop-points.

Comment: I know that `ScrollViewProxy` works with IDs, that's also why I tried to circumvent the limitation using a single rectangle with a static ID whose position changed according to my needs. Too bad it didn't work, it looks like at the moment the content appears the IDs and positions are registered once and for all and do not update when the content changes. It's such a shame cause with `Introspect` this takes no more than 4 lines.

Comment: The difference between the solution we have here, and the the film example that you linked to, is that the user is able to adjust the scroll position here by dragging the main view. In other words, the user is not dependent on a Slider to adjust the main view. This means, the rectangles for building up the main view just need to correspond to the positions you want to scroll to programmatically. If we are talking about spectogram inspection then surely there will not be thousands of these?

Comment: Yeah let me throw in some numbers from my use case: my current default settings for the spectrogram are the following: window size: 2048, hop count: 4 (ie an offset between two time bins of 512 samples), sampling frequency of 44100 Hz, audio durations of about 3 minutes. Assuming a three minutes with these settings you get (7938000 - 2048)/512 = 15000 pixels, assuming a time bin takes one pixel in the output image.